# ADF data flow concat expression with single quote

Tags: sql, expression, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow, quote

I need to generate a SQL string using Azure data flow expression builder, but it won't allow me to add a single quote between my string using Concat function

I need to have a SQL string as below

```
SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE myDate <= '2019-10-10'
```

Here 2019-10-10 is coming from a parameter, and so expression which I build is like below

```
concat('SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE myDate >=','''',$ToDate,'''')
```

but above statement unable to parse expression.

The result will be executed as a SQL query. SQL query doesn't allow double quote. It has to be single quote.

This is easily achievable using data factory expression but not with azure data flow expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, you can do it this way:

'select * from saleslt.product  where myDate >= \'' + $ToDate + '\''

Essentially, just use + with escaped single quotes.

We're releasing a new string interpolation feature next week to make this much easier. Any expression, column, or parameter can be used inside double-quotes.

Your example will look like this:

"SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE myDate >='{$ToDate}'"

Much easier. I'll send out an announcement once the feature is ready next week.

Comment: fyi, the string interpolation in SQL Sources with Queries is *horribly* broken at the moment - I can't make it parse in any format, even the literal examples provided here or in the docs. Likewise it can't handle multiline definitions.

Comment: Multiline is not supported in SQL scripts using string interpolation and no \n either

Answer (score 2):

I called Azure Support and they told me a using bellow expression can help us add single quote to the Column or data :

```
toString('\''+ toString(byName('col2'))+ '\'')
```

So your  expression should be:

`concat('SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE myDate >=',toString('\''+ toString(byName('$ToDate'))+ '\'') )`

I tested in my date type column2 and it works well.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

After doing a lot of trials and experiments,
I got a solution for this,Use ''(one extra quote) instead of '. it will work.
for example.

```
@concat('Select batchid from execution_Log where Execution_status=''Success'' and Hierachy_ID = ', pipeline().parameters.Hierachy_ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify by adding 4 comma at both side to parameter. This will applicable when you passing SQL query and the parameter is in String format.

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM DW_DEV.Schema_Name.DEMO_CONFIG WHERE SOURCESYSTEM = ','''',pipeline().parameters.SourceSystem,'''')
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a lot of trouble with this, trying to pass 2 timestamp variables with quotes around them. Lots of trail and error and I was able to use string interpolation to get it going. Expression ended up being:

```
"SELECT c.data.user_id ... FROM c WHERE c.data.date > '{toString($StartTime)}' AND c.data.date <= '{toString($EndTime)}'"
```